# Wrong path set and now .bashrc throws errors

Tags: bash

As a part of an installation process I had to add certain directories to the default PATH. I have given wrong path by mistake and rebooted the system . Now nothing (ls,vim,vi etc) works since I have messed up my .bashrc file. Can anyone tell me how to undo this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
PATH="/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
```

then fix your .bashrc

Comment: You missed `/usr/local/bin` for any local software installation; and also `/opt` and `/usr/local/sbin`. Sorry, actually he asked for fixing, so I added all the possibilities. :D

Comment: Thanks a lot. This solved the issue. It feels like my terminal has resurrected :D