# How to edit corrupted bash profile

Tags: bash

I exported a PATH that is incorrect in my bash profile, and I can no longer open it to edit it.  Even worse, my terminal is basically completely broken because of this.

If I run `vim ~/.bash_profile`

I get the following errors:

> -bash: vim: command not found
>
> -bash: sed: command not found

If I try to use a command like `ls` I get:

> -bash: ls: command not found
>
> -bash: sed: command not found

How can I fix my bash profile if I can't even edit it?

Comment: Use the full path: `/usr/bin/vim ~/.bash_profile`.

Comment: You can type the full path to `vim`, which is probably `/usr/bin/vim`.

Comment: You can also type `/bin/sh` to get into a shell that doesn't process `.bash_profile` in the first place.

Comment: Once I've edited it, how can I refresh my bash profile.  Running `source ~/.bash_profile` still gives me errors.

Comment: See: [Wrong path set and now .bashrc throws errors](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31891864/3776858)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your terminal isn't broken, bash is just lost because it is using this broken PATH variable, which you have saved in ~/.bash_profile. So, when you reload (source) your configuration, bash is simply re-reading from the same broken PATH.

To fix it, you must either edit the configuration or replace the file.

**In the meantime, you can restore (what is likely) your default PATH temporarily, for the current shell session, from the command-line:** `PATH="/bin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:"`

Otherwise, you must include the full path to each command you enter (as commented above) since bash no longer knows which directories to look in for these programs (commands).

Try `/usr/bin/vim ~/.bash_profile` to open the file for editing. 
If you'd like to instead remove the file, try: `/bin/rm ~/.bash_profile` But don't forget to replace it!

Once you've successfully, edited or replaced the file, you need to source it for it to be loaded with each new instance of bash: `. ~/.bash_profile`.

Also, it is better to place your configuration in the `~/.bashrc` file, though this would not have prevented the same situation from happening.