# "bash: sed: command not found" RHEL7 when installing SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, linux, bash, path, redhat

NEED HELP - LINUX NEWBIE - BROKEN LINUX RHEL7

While installing the mssql-tools on RHEL7 and following instructions to add the path for the mssql-tools, we added the following commands:

```
echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools/bin"' >> ~/.bash_profile
echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools/bin"' >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
```

After rebuilding the server for a second time, I've reached this Microsoft step again.  As it is the cause for my broken copy of RHEL7, having a way to do this properly and not incorrectly as listed above would be helpful.   Most articles list about 50 ways to do this.  I'm looking for one way only and it will be nice if the one way actually works and I don't spend another part of my life rebuilding the server again.

```
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-red-hat?view=sql-server-ver15
```

I created an issue in Github for this failing.

```
https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/sql-docs/issues/7288
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39795766/how-to-edit-corrupted-bash-profile  might help.  I can get at least "ls" to work again.

Comment: You may have better luck on the [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I'm guessing someone looked at the code and decided it was correct and dinged me for that.  I did not have any success at making it work.

Answer (score 0):

The article listed here seems to do the trick

```
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/174277/getting-sqlcmd-sqlcmd-command-not-found-in-linux
```

Long and short is the PATH should work as a join if it works like it does in Windows but I wound up using

```
sudo ln -s /opt/mssql-tools/bin/* /usr/local/bin/
```

to join that location with the user bin.  There is probably more to it since security is always number one, but at least I was able to complete the installation of SQL Server on the RHEL7 release.