# Broke my terminal with a bad PATH

Tags: command-line, path, bash

I put an invalid path into my `bashrc` and now my terminal doesn't work.  I've deleted my `bash_profile` as well as my `bashrc` and I still can't get it to work.

Every command I use in terminal gives me the error:

> sh: parse_git_branch: command not found

This was something I had in my `bash_profile` for git autocompletion.  The problem is once I've deleted the files using `/bin/rm <file>`, I can't apply my changes with `source ~/.bash_profile` because it's giving me errors.  I've looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39795766/how-to-edit-corrupted-bash-profile), and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31891864/wrong-path-set-and-now-bashrc-throws-errors), but I still am having no luck.

How can I fix my command line after breaking things like this?

Comment: Please ask your sysadmin or ask at [Super User](http://superuser.com/tour).

Comment: You could just open a new terminal, or logout/login. Or reboot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can export a correct PATH in your current session using a command similar to :

`export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin`

After using this, you should be able to source your bashrc.

Answer (score 0):

**You can always change your path right on the command line for the rest of the current shell session: `PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/sbin:"`**

**Exporting the PATH won't solve your problem**. It will only export the value of PATH to child shells/processes. This only achieves the same thing as resetting/changing the PATH variable from the command-line (as shown above), because your scope is limited to the current shell process (and its children) while you are working within that shell environment (working from the command-line). *If you open a new terminal (start a new login shell, which is a parent process), bash will still be trying to read from the resource files* (.bash_profile and .bashrc), *which no longer exist*.

So, we need to be able to widen our scope and tell bash that we want to make changes for all future bashes (shell processes--new shells, shells within shells, etc.), and the way that is done is by writing those statements in the resource files.

Once you set your PATH there, every shell session will spawn with those resources (all the aliases, commands, variables, and functions stored in those files), loaded, regardless of whether you export it or not, since each shell process will always consult those files before it does anything else (so they effectively pre-emptively import what you are trying to export to them).

bash is like any other script or program. You took away all its inputs and pointers and shortcuts, and now its just been made pretty dumb, so you've got to be explicit with everything you do till you can teach it where to look for stuff (give it a PATH to search) and shorten your conversations with it.

If you don't have a backup of your .bash_profile, here's one that you can use:

```
    # This loads in the configuration in .bashrc
    # Put all configuration in there!
    if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
        source ~/.bashrc
    fi
```

And here's a .bashrc that can get you started:

```
    export PATH="/bin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:"
```